# Find all newer events logged by application after a certain date in splunk

Tags: detection, splunk, anomaly-detection

**Question:** How can we find diff between log statements before and after a given date.

**Applicability:**  Let's say we release a new application code and I want to be able to see all new events that application has started logging.

Now definition of new is very vague here but any suggestion would help.  Idea is that splunk should be able to compare type of events were being logged earlier and only show new events that were not present before.

That would help finding any new Exceptions Errors or Warning that are being logged and not yet surfaced as a failed customer interaction.

**Example:**  After a new code release,  our application started logging an WARN event regarding "open file handlers" that kept building up over the time and ultimately reached a stage where no more unix file handlers were available to process any new request.

Answer (score 0):

If these are internal applications, I presume this means you *also* have custom `props.conf` and `transforms.conf` for the logs?

If you add new field extractions because of newer logging contents, then you will only *see* those newer fields in the newer data - because they won't exist in the older data